# neo4j query to find indirect paths runs extremely slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (a:Author {id:'author_1'}),
(art:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'})
WITH a, art
MATCH r=((a)-[*2..4]-(art))
RETURN r
```

In a database with roughly 1.3 million nodes and 8 million relations this query runs forever. Is there anything I can do?

There are indexes on :Author and :Article id

===============

[image]

Comment: match r=(a:Author {id:'author_1'})-[*2..4]-(art:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'}) return r should be sufficient no ? Can you post the PROFILE (or EXPLAIN) for that query ?

Comment: This warning is in the explain: This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.
If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this will build a cartesian product between all those parts. This may produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing. While occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate the query that avoids the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a relationship between the different parts or by using OPTIONAL MATCH (identifier is: (art))

Comment: I also tried to limit the results to 5 but this doesn't help a lot

Comment: Try explain with this query: `MATCH r=(:Author {id:'author_1'})-[*2..4]-(:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'})`
return r

Comment: How many rows your query returns ?
What is the result of those queries :
`MATCH (a:Author {id:'author_1'}) RETURN count(*)`
`MATCH (art:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'}) RETURN count(*)`

Comment: both matches return 1

Comment: no change in the query execution plan

Comment: when I replaced match with optional match, the query executed for 20 seconds

Comment: seems it's ok now with optional match and limit 5

Comment: Can you EXPLAIN the query, expand all elements of the query plan, and add the screenshot of the plan to your description? Also, what version of Neo4j are you using, and is there any way to restrict your expansion to only use certain relationships, or confine its direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the query planner can sometimes use an inefficient approach when matching to patterns connecting two nodes you already know.

In this case, the planner takes one node as the start node, expands to all possible nodes from the given pattern, and then applies a filter on all of those nodes to see if it's the other node at the end of the match. This is unnecessary property access, especially with large numbers of matched nodes.

The better approach is for both your start and end node to be looked up via the index, then perform expansions from one of those nodes, and use a hash join to determine which of those end nodes is the same as the end node you're looking for. This approach only uses property access once when matching to the id of the end node in question (instead of for every single node found at the end of the expansion).

The trick right now is how to get Neo4j to use this approach in the planner. This may work:

```
MATCH (a:Author {id:'author_1'}),
(art:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'})
MATCH r=((a)-[*2..4]-(end))
WHERE end = art
RETURN r
```

At the least, I'd expect this to be about as fast as your approach using an OPTIONAL MATCH.

Comment: you're right. I've learned how to use profile and was able to find that also. My final query is a little bit different from yours but has a similar idea. will check your execution plan latter for comparison

Answer (score 0):

The first two matches are not necessary. Remove it and try:

```
MATCH r=(:Author {id:'author_1'})-[*2..4]-(:Article {id:'PMID:21473878'})
return r
```

Comment: absolutely the same result

Comment: when relations are limited to 3 [*2..3] , it needs 3 seconds which is also very slow according me

Comment: I believe that the issue is exclusively related to the size of the database... At first look, this is a very simple query... So I don't know if you can do anything about related to the query. What is your hardware limitation?

Comment: In fact the first 2 matches makes the search bearable. It uses an index scan on those 2 nodes and than builds cartesian product between them. Which limit db nodes access to the number of nodes in my db 1.2m atm. If I didn't define those 2 nodes in front It finds the first node and than the cartesian product is 88millions on which a filter with the second node is applied and that ran forever.